# Как вывести все последующие строки после выбранного

Tags: sql, mysqli

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как вывести последующие элементы после (например) `'unicalCode' = '2242'`

нараметр `LIMIN` мне не подходит мне нужно чтобы именно через параментh `unicalCode` например `'unicalCode' = '2242'`, `'unicalCode' = '3272'`, и т.д

Comment: Какая сортировка определяет именно такой порядок записей? определяет, какие "до" и какие "после"? сортировка по `id`?

Answer (score 0):

Определите `id` записи `unicalCode = '2242'`, затем сделайте выборку с условием `id >= НайденноеЗначение`